# Can't register an entity in my database with form symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I'm new with symfony and I try to register an entity in my base with form.
Here is the form:

```
<?php
namespace App\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\MoneyType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TelType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\NumberType;

class OfferType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('title', TextType::class, array('label' => '*Title: ' , 'attr' => array('class' => 'input2')))
        ->add('nameofgame', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Name of the Game:','attr' => array('class' => 'create button1')))
        ->add('description', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Description: ' , 'attr' => array('class' => 'input2')))
        ->add('price', MoneyType::class, array('label' => '*Price: ' , 'attr' => array('class' => 'input2')))
        ->add('numbertelephone', TelType::class, array('label' => 'Telephone Number:','attr' => array('class' => 'create button1')))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Post Offer','attr' => array('class' => 'create button1')))
    ;
}
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/BoardFind/Trade/RegisterOffer", name="RegisterOffer")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $Offer = new TradeOffer();
    $form = $this->createForm(OfferType::class, $Offer);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $Offer = $form->getData();
        echo maleee;
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $session = $this->get('session');
        $userId = $session->get("id");
        $user = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(User::class)->find($userId);
        $Offer->setUser($user);
        $Offer->setTraderName($user->getName());
        $Offer->setTraderLastName($user->getLastName());
        $Offer->setUsername($user->getUsername());
        $Offer->setTraderEmail($user->getEmail());

        $entityManager->persist($Offer);
        $entityManager->flush();

        $flashbag = $this->get('session')->getFlashBag();
        $flashbag->add("SuccessfullRegister", "You successfully registered your offer!");
        return $this->redirectToRoute('Trade');
    }

    return $this->render('home/RegisterOffer.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));

}
```

When I try to register an offer it says that "Expected argument of type "App\Entity\double", "double" given." but the thing is that I think the property of the entity is right.
Here is the property:

```
/**
 * @Assert\Type("double")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $price;
```

If you want image of the error [here](https://ibb.co/vjg8jKz) it is.
So where is the problem?

Comment: It seems that PHP's type system does not allow using `double` as a type hint or return type. This could be, because it is just an alias for `float`. In your setter and getter try replacing `double` with `float`. You might also want to use `string` instead if you use strict typing and safer floating point calculations using the `bcmath`-extension.

Comment: Thanks float helped write a answer so I can mark it as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP `double` is an alias for `float`. When using scalar type hints or return types this alias is not supported and the actual type must be used instead. This behavior is comparable with `bool` being supported, but not `boolean`.

In other words in your getters & setters you have to refer to to `float` instead.